# Implementing cancel in Erlang

Tags: design-patterns, erlang, gen-server

Say I have a gen_server that does some long running task. What would be the best and cleanest way to cancel the task?

```
-module(example_srv).

-behaviour(gen_server).

%% API
-export([start_link/0]).

%% gen_server callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
     terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-record(state, {}).

%%====================================================================
%% API
%%====================================================================
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: start_link() -> {ok,Pid} | ignore | {error,Error}
%% Description: Starts the server
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [], []).

%%====================================================================
%% gen_server callbacks
%%====================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: init(Args) -> {ok, State} |
%%                         {ok, State, Timeout} |
%%                         ignore               |
%%                         {stop, Reason}
%% Description: Initiates the server
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
init([]) ->
    {ok, #state{}}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: %% handle_call(Request, From, State) -> {reply, Reply, State} |
%%                                      {reply, Reply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                      {noreply, State} |
%%                                      {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                      {stop, Reason, Reply, State} |
%%                                      {stop, Reason, State}
%% Description: Handling call messages
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_call(long_run, _From, State) ->
    other_module:long_running_function(),
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State};        
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: handle_cast(Msg, State) -> {noreply, State} |
%%                                      {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                      {stop, Reason, State}
%% Description: Handling cast messages
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: handle_info(Info, State) -> {noreply, State} |
%%                                       {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                       {stop, Reason, State}
%% Description: Handling all non call/cast messages
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: terminate(Reason, State) -> void()
%% Description: This function is called by a gen_server when it is about to
%% terminate. It should be the opposite of Module:init/1 and do any necessary
%% cleaning up. When it returns, the gen_server terminates with Reason.
%% The return value is ignored.
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Func: code_change(OldVsn, State, Extra) -> {ok, NewState}
%% Description: Convert process state when code is changed
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Internal functions
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your long-lived computation is synchronous--part of the gen_server loop--you won't be able to interrupt it. Any message you might send to the gen_server process will be received *after* the synchronous computation is complete.

I would suggest you spawn_link a side process to perform the computation which messages passes the result back to the gen_server. Keep the reference to this side process in the gen_server's state. At the same time as spawning, spawn a [`timer`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html) which will act as limit to the length of the side-computation. If your handle_info receives a timeout while the side-computation is running, kill the side process and bail out. If you receive the result from the side-computation first, kill the timer.

Comment: Either this, or send a signal to the process though `exit/2`.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across the Middleman pattern.

This idea is that your gen-server spawns a middle-man process/gen_server that has the responsibility of running/monitoring a process, this middleman process can then be used to interact with the long running process.

Incase you want to cancel a long running process, you would just send the middle man process a message to kill the worker - (the middle man actions could to some extend be handled by the gen_server)